# Sopaui teardown script

Tags: soapui

i am using teardown script for my API testing to chnage the header values after each run, now i have scripted like on first run of my test suite, om the last test suite i have added a teardown script like below

```
testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("BRAND_TYPE","L")
testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("BRAND_CLIENT","LD")
```

So this will update my header and I can run my test suite for second time but I have to change the headers for running test suite for the third time, so can any one suggest the tear down script please.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you please make it bit more clear?

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic, you will just have to code the entire logic:

```
def brandTypeFirstRun = "first_value"
def brandTypeSecondRun = "second_value"
def brandTypeThirdRun = "third_value"

def bradTypeCurrentValue = testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("BRAND_TYPE")

if ( bradTypeCurrentValue == brandTypeFirstRun )
    testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("BRAND_TYPE", brandTypeSecondRun)
else if ( bradTypeCurrentValue == brandTypeSecondRun )
    testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("BRAND_TYPE", brandTypeThirdRun)
else if ( bradTypeCurrentValue == brandTypeThirdRun )
    testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("BRAND_TYPE", brandTypeFirstRun)
```